# Vue js returns an an empty array

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm new to vue js,

my method fetchedData already fetch and set the data in the vuex store, the data is complete and perfect in the vuex store. The actions fetched the data and commit, the mutations set the data to the state, and the state in getters show the full data but in the template.component the array is still empty. here's the code:

the whole template:

```
<template>
  <base-dashboard :validators-route="validatorsRoute">
    <v-form @submit.prevent="submitUpdate">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-container>
            <v-text-field
              hide-no-data
              hide-details
              :label="validatorDetail"
              variant="outlined"
              disabled
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-container>
          <v-container>
            <!-- <v-row v-for="(items, key) in splitItems" :key="key">
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-checkbox
                  :label="renderTitle(key)"
                  class="font-weight-bold"
                  @click="toggleAll(key)"
                ></v-checkbox>
                <v-table height="300">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(itemRow, index) in items" :key="index">
                      <td v-for="item in itemRow" :key="item.permission">
                        <v-checkbox
                          :label="item"
                          v-model="permissions"
                          :value="item"
                          @click="handleCheck(key)"
                        ></v-checkbox>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </v-table>
              </v-col>
            </v-row> -->
          </v-container>

          <v-container class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
            <v-btn
              class="pb-8 pt-4 bt-st my-button"
              style="background-color: #cfdbd5; font-weight: 700"
              :disabled="!formValidation"
              @click="submitUpdate"
              >UPDATE
            </v-btn>
          </v-container>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </base-dashboard>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import BaseDashboard from "../components/BaseDashboard.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default {
  components: { BaseDashboard },
  emits: ["close-create", "set-error", "refetch-data"],
  props: ["dialog", "purpose"],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const store = useStore();
    const router = useRouter();

    const loading = ref(false);
    const select = ref(null);
    const permissions = ref([]);
    const storedPermissions = ref([]);
    const allPermissions = ref({
      admin: false,
      roles: false,
      permissions: false,
      access: false,
      validator: false,
      validatorPermission: false,
      validatorAccess: false,
      service: false,
      validatorRole: false,
      validatorRolePermission: false,
      validatorFeature: false,
      validatorAccessFeature: false,
      validatorAccessGate: false,
      validatorAccessRate: false,
    });

    const validatorsRoute = computed(
      () => store.getters["admin/getAdminRoutes"]
    );

    const fetchData = async () => {
      await store.dispatch("admin/setAdminAccess");
      await store.dispatch("admin/setAdminPermissions");
    };

    const validatorDetail = computed(
      () => store.getters["admin/getEvalAccess"]
    );

    const adminAccess = computed(() => store.getters["admin/getAdminAccess"]);

    const rolePermissions = adminAccess.value.filter(
      (access) => access["roleName"] === validatorDetail.value
    );

    const massagePermission = rolePermissions.map(
      (permission) => permission["permissionName"]
    );

    permissions.value = massagePermission;
    storedPermissions.value = rolePermissions;

    const splitItems = rolePermissions.reduce((acc, role) => {
      const render = role["permissionName"].toLowerCase().split(" ");

      delete role.index;
      if (
        (render.includes("admin") && render.includes("role")) ||
        render.includes("admin")
      ) {
        if (!acc.admin) {
          acc.admin = [];
        }
        acc.admin.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (
        render.includes("role") &&
        !render.includes("admin") &&
        !render.includes("validator")
      ) {
        if (!acc.roles) {
          acc.roles = [];
        }
        acc.roles.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("permission")) {
        if (!acc.permissions) {
          acc.permissions = [];
        }
        acc.permissions.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("access")) {
        if (!acc.access) {
          acc.access = [];
        }
        acc.access.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (
        (render.includes("validator") && render.includes("role")) ||
        render.includes("validatorrole")
      ) {
        if (!acc.validatorRole) {
          acc.validatorRole = [];
        }
        acc.validatorRole.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatorpermission")) {
        if (!acc.validatorPermission) {
          acc.validatorPermission = [];
        }
        acc.validatorPermission.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatoraccess")) {
        if (!acc.validatorAccess) {
          acc.validatorAccess = [];
        }
        acc.validatorAccess.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatorfeature")) {
        if (!acc.validatorFeature) {
          acc.validatorFeature = [];
        }
        acc.validatorFeature.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatoraccessfeature")) {
        if (!acc.validatorAccessFeature) {
          acc.validatorAccessFeature = [];
        }
        acc.validatorAccessFeature.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatoraccessgate")) {
        if (!acc.validatorAccessGate) {
          acc.validatorAccessGate = [];
        }
        acc.validatorAccessGate.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validatoraccessrate")) {
        if (!acc.validatorAccessRate) {
          acc.validatorAccessRate = [];
        }
        acc.validatorAccessRate.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("service")) {
        if (!acc.service) {
          acc.service = [];
        }
        acc.service.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else if (render.includes("validator")) {
        if (!acc.validator) {
          acc.validator = [];
        }
        acc.validator.push({ permission: role["permissionName"] });
      } else {
        if (!acc.validatorRolePermission) {
          acc.validatorRolePermission = [];
        }
        acc.validatorRolePermission.push({
          permission: role["permissionName"],
        });
      }

      return acc;
    }, {});

    const renderTitle = (key) => {
      const words = key.match(/[A-Z]?[a-z]+/g);

      if (!words) return "";

      const capitalizedWords = words.map((word) => {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
      });

      return capitalizedWords.join(" ");
    };

    const listItems = computed(() => {
      const roleNames = roles.value.map((role) => role.roleName);
      return roleNames;
    });

    const submitUpdate = async () => {
      const arr = [...permissions.value];
      for (const key in allPermissions.value) {
        const selected = splitItems[key];

        if (selected !== undefined) {
          const massageData = selected.map(
            (permission) => permission["permission"]
          );
          const value = allPermissions.value[key];
          if (value) {
            arr.push(...massageData);
          }
        }
      }

      function filterMatchingObjects(arrA, arrB) {
        const uniqueDescriptions = new Set(arrA);

        const matchingObjects = arrB.filter((obj) =>
          uniqueDescriptions.has(obj.permissionName)
        );

        return matchingObjects;
      }

      const objectMatched = filterMatchingObjects(arr, storedPermissions.value);

      const { modalClose } = await store.dispatch("admin/deleteAccess", {
        permissionId: objectMatched,
      });

      if (modalClose) router.replace("/dashboard/admin/access");
    };

    const toggleAll = (key) => {
      const selected = splitItems[key];

      allPermissions.value[key] = !allPermissions.value[key];

      const massageData = selected.map(
        (permission) => permission["permission"]
      );

      const filtered = permissions.value.filter((permission) => {
        return !selected.some((select) => select.permission === permission);
      });
      if (!allPermissions.value[key]) {
        permissions.value = [...filtered, ...massageData];
      } else {
        permissions.value = filtered;
      }
    };

    const handleCheck = (key) => {
      allPermissions.value[key] = false;
    };

    const formValidation = computed(() => {
      if (permissions.value !== storedPermissions.value) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    return {
      select,
      loading,
      listItems,
      splitItems,
      permissions,
      formValidation,
      validatorsRoute,
      validatorDetail,
      toggleAll,
      renderTitle,
      handleCheck,
      submitUpdate,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

this is the action:

```
 async setAdminAccess(context) {
    const token = context.rootGetters["sessions/getToken"];
    context.commit("sessions/setLoading", true, { root: true });
    const res = await fetchAdminAccess(token);

    if (res?.response?.status === 401) {
      const {
        status,
        data: { message, error },
      } = res.response;
      context.commit("sessions/setLoading", false, { root: true });

      context.commit(
        "sessions/setError",
        { status, message, title: error },
        { root: true }
      );
      return res;
    }

    if (res.status !== 401) {
      const fetchedData = [...res?.data?.records];

      const data = await standardConvert(fetchedData, ["roleId"]);

      context.commit("setAdminAccess", data);
      context.commit("sessions/setLoading", false, { root: true });
    }
  },
```

this in the getters:

```
 getAdminAccess(state) {
    return state.adminAccess;
  },
```

sorry if things seems obvious to you

I already tried onMounted, I already rewriting them, still nothing works

Comment: Is all the code relevant to the question? It's a lot to parse through.  It's not even clear what empty array you're talking about. 
 Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76751553/edit) the question and trim the code to the minimal code necessary that still shows the issue and **explain** what the different parts of the code is or should be doing.